# Force on Magnetic Dipole in Non-Uniform field

Tags: calculus, summation, vectors, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

This question stems from physics, but it is the mathematics aspect which troubles me I believe. However, if you feel it doesn't belong here please feel free to move it to the physics forum.

---

It can be shown that the force on an electric dipole in a non-uniform electric field is found as:
$$F_i = p_j \frac{\partial E_i}{\partial x_j} $$
which in vector-form corresponds to:
$$\vec{F} = (\vec{p} \cdot \nabla) \vec{E} $$

However, using the fact that $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0 $ the summation can also be written:
$$F_i = p_j \frac{\partial E_j}{\partial x_i} $$

---

Now, for a magnetic dipole the force in a non-uniform magnetic field can be shown to be

$$F_i = m_j \frac{\partial B_j}{\partial x_i} (\star)$$

, which equivalent to the second expression for the electric case. However, for a magnetic field we don't in general have $\nabla \times \vec{B} = 0 $, meaning that I am not convinced that we can go back to the first form seen in the electrical case.

My question is therefore: **Is there any pretty vector form of expression** $\star$?

I am aware $\vec{F} = \nabla(\vec{m} \cdot\vec{B}) $ is a valid option **if** $\vec{m}$ is constant, but what if it is not?

Comment: $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ is not always true. The equation actually reads $\nabla \times \vec{E} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec{B}.$

Comment: From [Classical Electrodynamics 2nd Edition](https://books.google.se/books/about/Classical_electrodynamics.html?id=_7rvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) by [J. D. Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_David_Jackson_(physicist)):
$$\mathbf{F} = (\mathbf{m} \times \nabla) \times \mathbf{B} = \nabla(\mathbf{m}\cdot\mathbf{B}) - \mathbf{m}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}) \tag{5.68}$$
and, since $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B} = 0$,
$$\mathbf{F} = \nabla(\mathbf{m}\cdot\mathbf{B}) \tag{5.69}$$
He writes: "This result holds even for time-varying external fields."

Comment: The 3rd edition can be found on Scribd:  
https://www.scribd.com/doc/52999846/38990847-Jackson-J-D-Classical-Electrodynamics-PDF
Although the equations have changed since 2nd edition, you can still look for equation (5.69).

Comment: Where have you seen the derivations that give different formulas for the electrostatic and the electromagnetic cases?

Comment: @md2perpe I agree that $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ is not always true, I suppose that the derivation assumes no time-varying B fields present. The derivations I have seen come from my uni lecture notes (Cambridge) and not from a book unfortunately, they are based on considering small magnetisation currents and their net effect inside a field.

Comment: @md2perpe I took a look at the book you sent, but unfortunately the equations seem to have changed numbering. (5.69) stated $\vec{F} = \nabla \times (\vec{m} \times \vec{B}) = (\vec{m} \cdot \nabla) \vec{B} = \nabla(\vec{m} \cdot \vec{B})$, but the first form was based on some previous identity which isn't crystal clear to me at first glance. My lecturenotes explicitly state that $\vec{F} = \nabla(\vec{m} \cdot \vec{B})$ only holds for constant $\vec{m}$.

Comment: @md2perpe I have seen suggestions that $\vec{F} = (\vec{m} \cdot \nabla) \vec{B}$ or that $\vec{F} = \vec{m} \cdot \nabla(\vec{B})$ but I am not 100% sure how any of these follow from $F_i = m_j \frac{\partial B_j}{\partial x_i}$, which according to my notes is the most general form.

Comment: When you consider $\mathbf{m}$ not being constant, are you then thinking of a magnetic dipole field/density instead of a pointlike dipole?

Comment: @md2perpe I am thinking of a pointlike dipole, but one that is not rigid and can rotate, so it's components vary with time.

Comment: But then $\mathbf{m}$ doesn't depend on space so $F_i = m_j \partial_i B_j = \partial_i (m_j B_j)$ so $\mathbf{F} = \nabla (\mathbf{m} \cdot \mathbf{B}).$